# What's the best place to display important information on mobile screen

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline, ux-integration

I am working on a fitness tracking app and need to display few statistic on the home page. My home page will be entirely covered by map with some opacity and on top of it I need to display few information as show in below screenshot.
What will be best place to keep it, at left side or right side? and what will be better vertical alignment(center, bottom or top).

Also if somebody have some demographic or did some research on where the user looks more on the screen and what's the first site on the screen where use looks at after an app is open than it will be much helpful.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the map?

Comment: It will track current user's movement.

Comment: Cheers, sounds important to the functionality and the UI, why the transparency on it?

Comment: It's not that transparent, the color contrast is quite awesome that user will not miss any information from the map, just I am not sure where to place above statistics on the screen. Sorry, I can't share the UI here.

Comment: If the user is tracking their movement for a particular activity, do they need to see tracking for an activity they may not be doing at the time? For example, they may be running, are the steps and biking distance relevant during a running activity?

Answer (score 2):

**Make field study**

You should really test that when users are running and using your app. Try to experiment putting the statistics on all corners of your app and see what feedback you will get. This is the safest and most valid way to answer to your question.

However, if you don't have the time and resources to conduct field study you can

**Research how your competitors has fixed this problem**

You should look at the top 5 fitness tracking apps and see how they've layed out this particular screen. If all apps are using the same layout, the best thing to do is be consistent with them and copy their layout. This way users that have experience with similar apps will have existing knowledge of how to use your app.

Answer (score 1):

In countries where reading is left->right, top->bottom, **top left** is the best place to put important information.  Second choice is **dead center**.  Our eyes orientate by going first to the center for an instant, then to the place where we start reading.

Painters have known for centuries how to direct viewers' eyes. Here's some information about doing that for advertising: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/eye-tracking-studies/